# Watch multiple PHP CLI output streams without writing to file

Tags: php, command-line-interface, tail

I am writing a PHP scripts (yes, it needs to stay PHP) that will take in data, categorize it, and eventually write it to a database.  During testing I would like to be able to watch it's multiple outputs, without writing huge logs.  Is this possible?

My initial thought was to use file_put_contents to put it's various streams into specific files, and use tail -f to watch these files.  Constantly overwriting the file contents, so as to not make one huge file, but one file that at any time has one entry in it.

This 'works', but on every write, tail outputs 'tail: xxx.txt: file truncated', which is distracting.

Does anyone know of any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Something I didn't think of:

People are always talking about directing stdout  to /dev/null.  The common syntax is `tail test.txt -f > /dev/null 2>&1`.  This syntax essentially says 'send stdout to /dev/null, and send stdio 2 (stderror) to whereever the last place we were sending things to is (/dev/null)'.  So, simply `tail test.txt -f 2>/dev/null` and stderrors go away, and tailing a constantly rotating file wins.

Such a noob question..  gosh.